# How to delete the Logs on Stripe in a test environment

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe to carry out some test transactions on supposed customers from a CodeIgniter application.
For some reason, to re-create a **Stripe > Plan** with the same old id and name online or to re-enter the Stripe customer into the **Stripe > Customers**
through the API I have to clear the test data. When I clear the test data it clears the test data except the Logs.

Now what happens when I re-create a **Stripe > Plan**, it automatically gets the deleted customer from the Logs. As I don't need the old customer in the plan as I might have changed its credentials.

So how to delete/clear the Logs on Stripe in a test environment?

Answer (score 30):

This is an older question, but a Google search brought me here, requiring an answer after my own trial and error (correct solution may have changed over time).

1. Login to the Stripe dashboard
2. Choose "Business Settings" on the bottom-left of the page.
3. Choose "Data" on the left menu.
4. Select the gray "Delete all test data..." button.
5. Select the red "Delete Now" button on the confirmation modal.
6. It may ask to confirm your password before proceeding.

Comment: 2020 June: Developers Tab on the left hand menu. On the next screen, very bottom, Click remove Test Data Button.

Answer (score 14):

As of Nov 21, 2019, the process is similar to Christopher Stevens answer, however things have moved around a little.

1. Login to the Stripe Dashboard
2. Click Settings in bottom left corner
3. Scroll to the Compliance and reporting section (at bottom of page)
4. Click the Data link
5. At bottom of page you should see after "Test data:" a button that says "Delete all test data..."

Stripe changes the UI often enough, that this answer will likely require ongoing maintenance.

Answer (score 14):

As of May 2, 2020, this has moved again.

1. Log into the Stripe Dashboard
2. Go to the Developers tab in the left sidebar
3. Scroll to the bottom
4. Click "Delete all test data..."

Answer (score 11):

Im not sure why but for me I had to go into "Developers" on the left hand menu. On the next screen at the very bottom there is a section to remove Test Data.

Answer (score 5):

As of August 8, 2020:

1. Go to your account, toggle "viewing test data" to ensure it's enabled.
2. Click on "Developers" on the sidebar.
3. At the bottom there is a section for "Test data". Hit the "Delete all test data..." button.

Answer (score 4):

Check your **Account Setting** (upper right corner) > **data**.

The last option says: *"Test Data: Delete all test data..."*

Got it from [Robin Thebe on wpguru.com: "How to delete Stripe test data"](https://www.wpguru.com.au/web-development-tips/delete-stripe-test-data/)

Answer (score 2):

After trial and error I came to know that in the Stripe interface there is no way to get rid of the logs, maybe it is due to give security in the pro environment. However I found out that there is an option to just make another account under the same stripe-user-email. On the creation of the new account we actually get rid of the logs. And we can just simply delete the old account.

**Note: Deletion of an account does not delete you from Stripe. Its just creation of an account with a different name. We can have many accounts with many names.**

Comment: This seems to require signing up to Stripe Connect.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete all the test data within the 'Developer' tab below: https://dashboard.stripe.com/developers